# How to represent [RETURN] key in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I am writing a technical document in MS Word 2007, which needs to show the reader how to execute some commands on the operating system.  Something like:

```
C:\script_dir> run.bat [RETURN]
```

Many technical books show a symbol for the [RETURN], which is what I would like to do -- not only to cut down on the length of the text, but also to eliminate any confusion about whether the reader should include that space between the "run.bat" and the [RETURN] key.

I looked through the stuff that's available through "Insert Symbol", but didn't see anything that looked like a good candidate.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

i think you're looking for the [downwards arrow with corner leftwards](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/21b5/index.htm)?

### ↵

- "carriage return arrow"
- `U+21B5`
- `&#8629;`
- `&crarr;`
- `Alt + 21B5`

Comment: Nice. Taught me something new :-).

Comment: I was looking all over for that. You beat me fair and square. :-)

Comment: Welcome to the ranks of the [Stackathletes](http://stackathlon.appspot.com/).

Comment: On Windows 7, I am unable to type Alt + 21B5. It simply opens the menu of the application I'm using. So if one converts the Unicode character number from hex to decimal, one would get 8629. Alt + 8629 appears to work, provided the current font contains the ↵ on that location.

Comment: As implied in my previous comment, not all fonts provide this symbol. One that does on Windows 7 is _Segoe UI Symbol_.

Comment: i would just copy&paste the character.

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend getting a keycap font (one example I quickly found is [Qwerty PC](http://www.identifont.com/find?font=Qwerty+PC&q=Go)), especially if you'll be representing keystrokes often throughout your documents. Make sure the font covers special keys like <kbd>Enter **↵**</kbd>. Some are free, and some aren't.

If you go this route, however, consider whether you'll need to embed the font so you can open the file on another computer.

Comment: And for anyone wondering how to represent keyboard shortcuts like displayed in the answer above: use the <kbd> html tag.

Comment: @oKtosiTe D'oh! I totally should have thought to mention that!

Comment: Well, it *is* somewhat off-topic, but I thought I'd mention it since I only recently found out about it myself. Cheers!

Comment: Is that a tag that is generally usable in all HTML? Or is it something peculiar to StackExchange markdown?

Comment: @eidylon It's standard HTML since HTML 2.0; see [the Computer phrase elements section of the HTML element article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Computer_phrase_elements) on Wikipedia for more info.

Comment: Cool! Learned my new thing for the day!  :)

Answer (score 2):

I generally use `<ENTER>` for my technical documentation, with a space after the last command. Then in the intro of the document you can say what it represents, and that the preceding space is just for formatting and should be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

This might need some explanation for your readers, but some use [the pilcrow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilcrow): ¶

Answer (score 0):

Thanks  I was hunting for this alt code for the return arrow character for weeks. . .

In MS Word and Wordpad, Alt 8629 appears in most fonts as a left right angle arrow but not in Excel or Windows. Thus it is similar to a carriage return and can be used for that but it is not a real carriage return symbol and depending upon the program it will behave differently.
ALT 8629 / ALT181  Box Drawings Vertical Single and Left Double

In MS 2019 Word  Insert tab >  Symbol, Subset Arrows, Third ros of arrows,  second from the left.